# ObjectDisposedException thrown when using the WritableBitmap

Tags: uwp, objectdisposedexception, writablebitmap

I am trying to convert the rendered stream from `RenderTargetBitmap` to the writable bitmap. I used the below code in button click and convert the stream to bitmap. If continuously converting the bitmap means it throws an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Code snippet

```
   RenderTargetBitmap rendererShapeViewBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream renderedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await rendererShapeViewBitmap.RenderAsync(button, (int)button.Width, (int)button.Height);
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, renderedStream);
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await rendererShapeViewBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(renderedStream);
        int heiht = rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelHeight;
        int width = rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelWidth;
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
            (uint)rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixelBuffer.ToArray());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();

        var bitmap1 = new WriteableBitmap(width, heiht);
        bitmap1.SetSource(renderedStream);

        var bitmap2 = new WriteableBitmap(width,heiht);
        bitmap2.SetSource(renderedStream);
```

Comment: I create image and pass the bitmap1  to the image source, it works well, there is no exception throw. Could share more detail about where the exception throw?

Comment: You should remove dataWriter.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Please refer to the sample https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvUeU89VQTJvgQV3-RqxyRYCALht    Click the button continuously in the sample.

Comment: Issue occurs only in release mode

Comment: @Santhiya, I have tested your code in release mode, it works well, there is no exception throw.

Comment: Continuously click the button

Comment: @santhiya did you ever solve your issue? I'm having a similar issue intermittently throws same exception..

Comment: Yes.." var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(renderedStream);" because of this line i got an exception. I removed this line. Now it is working.